# How to add style to div using LESS

Tags: html, css, less

I have div which I am trying to align the center of the page, but my style does not apply to the div. `centeralign` style class is inside .less file. How to do I write a class inside a less file and how to use that in html?

```css
.centeralign {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col centeralign">
  <p>align this div center</p>
  <div>
```

Comment: LESS requires a processor to convert to CSS.

Comment: Hi, you would need a compiler that makes the less file into a css file. The browser can't read less files. It shouldn't be that hard to find good tutorials on that. It also depends your project setup, if you should go with gulp/grunt/webpack/other. Gulp is pretty ok to get started with and setup the compiler, they even have a tutorial about that use case on their page. May I also ask why you use less over scss?

Comment: Compile less with for instance gulp . There is also a program that can help you out like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) .. Bet best is to learn a way that integrates it with the project like gulp will do. There are more options on the market.

Comment: The question is what framework do you use. You can modify files but you have to clean cache somewhere depending on what you use to compile your less files or you can directly add .less to browser : http://lesscss.org

Answer (score -2):

Your div class name does not match the name in the style.You named your div class "col centeralign" whereas in the style you named it "centrealign". Name them the same as in

```
<div class="centeralign">
```

align this div center

Style name

```
.centeralign {
  margin-top: 10%;
```

}

Comment: class "col centeralign"  says that 2 class are used 1st col 2nd centeralign, you can add any class you want.